Weird WPF behavior with PowerShell
I have got this simple script :
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window x:Name="AppWindow" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test" Width="600" Height="400">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AppWindow}">
        <ListBox Name="MyList" Margin="15,10,30,50">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FriendlyName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Name="OKBtn" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                Margin="0,0,30,10" Width="148" Height="23" IsEnabled="True" IsDefault="True" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@
$AppWindow = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml))
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | 
      ForEach-Object { Set-Variable  -Name ($_.Name) -Value $AppWindow.FindName($_.Name) -Scope Script }

# GUI Events
$AppWindow.Add_Loaded({
    $Script:MyList.ItemsSource = [array](Get-Disk)
})

$OKBtn.Add_Click({
   $Script:AppWindow.Close()
})

$AppWindow.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

It is working as expected when having two or more disks but shows nothing if I have got one disk only.
If I remove the Binding, and have a simple list
<ListBox Name="MyList" />

This works with one disk too.
If I leave the ListBox as is, with the binding into the DataTemplate, this is working if I populate the ItemsSource with this command :
$Script:MyList.ItemsSource = [array](Get-Disk | Select *)

To summarize :
$Script:MyList.ItemsSource = [array](Get-Disk)

The lonely object is typed :
$MyList.ItemsSource[0].GetType()
CimInstance

with
$Script:MyList.ItemsSource = [array](Get-Disk | Select *)
$MyList.ItemsSource[0].GetType()
PSCustomObject

So, I have replaced the first syntax with this one :
$Script:MyList.ItemsSource = [pscustomobject[]](Get-Disk)

this is working with one object only array, and the type is
$MyList.ItemsSource[0].GetType()
CimInstance

Same as the first way with the [array] cast, weird...
Note that this will be the same for other data types (eg. [array](Get-NetAdapter) and replace the binding with InterfaceAlias). But not for ActiveDirectory Module (eg. [array](Get-ADGroupMember MyOneMemberOnlyGroup) and replace the binding with SamAccountName.
Any idea to share on why this occurs this way especially that this is working for some datatypes as ADGroup ?
Thanks :)

What happens when you try with a list-type that isn't [array] as the item source? eg. $listbox.ItemsSource = [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]@(Get-NetAdapter)

same, as [pscustomobject[]], this is working, but [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[CimInstance]] does not, but $test=[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[CimInstance]](Get-Disk) directly into the console is ok and $test[0].GetType() is CimInstance actually. It is working with WPF when there is no bound data too...

It also works if you do $Script:MyList.ItemsSource = @(Get-Disk) or use the comma operator $Script:MyList.ItemsSource = ,(Get-Disk). Apparently the .ItemsSource always wants an array of type System.Collections.IEnumerable. I guess that is why they called it ItemsSource instead of the singular ItemSource..

@Theo, I know that but why array is ok for two members and not for one member only. Furthermore, with your syntax @(Get-Disk) - working, when you look at the type, it is the same as mine - not working - [array](Get-Disk) (Object[] with base type System.Array for ItemsSource and CimInstance for ItemsSource[0].... so what is really going on ?
